Vb.Net Using class must implement idisposable error, but idisposable is implemented
So i've created a custom class, with idisposable implemented, but for some reason, when trying to use this class in a using statement, it errors out saying that idisposable is not implemented.
the overarching idea here is that i've been tasked with cleaning up an application that is basically three hundred or so queries that were written as extremely painful unparameterized string builder queries. the idea i had, instead of trying to do this three hundred times, is to just create the parameterized query text, and then create a class that can hold an array of values that can be then looped through by passing the query text, and parameter array into a function that handles the querying;  i'm not sure whats missing here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc36010?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(BC36010)
Public Class QueryParamClass

        Implements IDisposable

        Private _ParamName As String
        Public Property ParamName() As String
            Get
                Return _ParamName
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                _ParamName = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private _ParamType As SqlDbType
        Public Property ParamType() As SqlDbType
            Get
                Return _ParamType
            End Get
            Set(value As SqlDbType)
                _ParamType = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _ParamData As VariantType


        Public Property ParamData() As VariantType
            Get
                Return _ParamData
            End Get
            Set(value As VariantType)
                _ParamData = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private disposedValue As Boolean
        Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
            If Not disposedValue Then
                If disposing Then
                    ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)
                End If

                ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
                ' TODO: set large fields to null
                disposedValue = True
            End If
        End Sub

        ' ' TODO: override finalizer only if 'Dispose(disposing As Boolean)' has code to free unmanaged resources
        ' Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        '     ' Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(disposing As Boolean)' method
        '     Dispose(disposing:=False)
        '     MyBase.Finalize()
        ' End Sub

        Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
            ' Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(disposing As Boolean)' method
            Dispose(disposing:=True)
            GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
        End Sub
    End Class

public sub randomtest()
      Using Qparam As New List(Of QueryParamClass)
          Qparam.Add(New QueryParamClass() With {.ParamName = "", .ParamType = Nothing, .ParamData = ""})
      End Using
end sub

I'm expecting this to allow me to have a using property that can pass my information into a function. i could always just run it as a dim as new, but i'm not sure thats going to be effective.

Your IDisposable implementation is pointless anyway, based on what you've done there. I suspect that you think that disposing does some magic that it doesn't. The point of disposing is to release unmanaged and/or managed resources. Unmanaged resource are things like file or window handles. Managed resources are .NET objects that hold other unmanaged or manages resources. All managed resources lead to unmanaged resources at some point. The memory occupied by an object is NOT a resource in this context. What exactly do you think you will achieve by disposing objects of this type?

The error being thrown was that the class did not implement idisposable. it was only included because attempting to have it in a using statement kept throwing that as an error. as others have pointed out, a list of my class, is not my class, and that including idisposable there does nothing.

This question is similar to: Proper use of the IDisposable interface. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Implementing IDisposable so that you can use a Using statement makes no sense, because the only reason to use a Using statement in the first place is because you want to dispose the object you created. What exactly do you think a Using block is doing for you here? If we know what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to achieve it, then we can explain how best to achieve it. It seems like what you're doing is totally pointless. Just create the objects, put them in a list if appropriate and use them. They'll be cleaned up by the system as usual.

The problem is that you're NOT using that class in a Using statement. This:
Using Qparam As New List(Of QueryParamClass)

is obviously creating a List(Of QueryParamClass), which does NOT implement IDisposable. This:
Using Qparam As New QueryParamClass

would be valid code. We can't really tell you want you should do because we don't really know what you're trying to achieve based on that code but a Using statement must create an object of a type the implements IDisposable and yours does not.

ultimately the goal was to create a class, that contains three different kinds of values, that could then pass those values into a for each statement, to create parameters for a query. eg
@Paramname, SqlDbType.VarChar, userinput

@Hideval, that has nothing to do with disposal so it doesn't really help explain why you're implementing IDisposable in the first place of what you were trying to achieve in that test code. Any object created with a Using statement can only be used within that Using block but you're not using anything in the code you posted so, again, it's not clear what that code weas supposed to achieve.

The class isn't a list. So this line
  Using Qparam As New List(Of QueryParamClass)

is the issue.  I created a dummy class.
Public Class DummyClass : Implements IDisposable
    Private theDate As DateTime
    Public Sub New()
        Me.theDate = DateTime.Now
    End Sub

#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

    ' IDisposable
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            End If

            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
            ' TODO: set large fields to null.
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class

This is how a list can be used so to speak,
    Dim myFooList As New List(Of DummyClass)
    myFooList.Add(New DummyClass)

    For Each item As DummyClass In myFooList
        Using foo As DummyClass = item
            'todo
        End Using
    Next

